# Loss of value using $_GET

Tags: php, get, urlencode

I use a form, collecting data entered in its fields. Using `onsubmit` I send data to another page to display the same.

i.e. `page1.php` has two input fields:

```
 pageNo = 1 //id and name of the input text field are the same, `pageID`

 //id and name of the input text field are the same, `someRandomValue`
 someRandomValue = "A long character string consisting of every possible character that can be typed from the keyboard"
```

I receive the above in `page2.php` **[page names are for display purposes alone**], using `$_GET`:

```
//on `echo` displays the desired result
$pageID = $_GET['pageNo']; 

// on `echo` does not print anything
$randomValue = $_GET['someRandomValue'];
```

However, the second one prints values as simple as `1`, `ab` and other small substrings, when directly typed via the address bar.

I have tried using the `$_GET` variable directly as well as `$randomValue` using all means - `echo`, `print_r` and `var_dump`.

In some cases. the sub string up to the first '#' is printed, and that too for smaller strings alone. Is it because of some special characters, I am not able to obtaining the desired result?

PS: The `onsubmit` is what I mean to tell about the standard form, submit button and onsubmit event that is usually used.

Sample URL: `?pageNo=a&someRandomValue=aslkfdjslfhdskljOU#OsssssssIU#IO$U#IO$`

When I print the second one alone, I get: `aslkfdjslfhdskljOU`

Comment: how are u posting the information retrieved by `$_GET`

Comment: 582846b38bd99862bfe29199d0f60ba1

Comment: I 'echo' it, if I understood your question right.

Comment: `$GET['pageNo']` this wont work... you're missing `_` ... assuming a typo?

Comment: A typo, indeed. Corrected it.

Comment: no no, as in how did you place the information in your query string

Comment: The get string cannot have special characters - they must be escaped or encoded (ie: urlencode). Also, get strings have a maximum length. The specific length is the minimum of your browser (which is usually 10-80k), your webserver (which is usually around 8k) and your PHP install, which is set to the webserver or to a specific value in php.ini. In your example, I doubt you are hitting the maximum query string limit.

Comment: Your mentioning of the symbol `#` leads me to believe it may have something to do with that. If you don't url encode `#` anything after that symbol in a url wont be posted to the server.

Comment: I tried getting that in a form (knew of the limit), and generated one on my own and entered it via the address bar.

Comment: But, why does it not work for the one I provided above? Is it because of the MAX. LIMIT.

Comment: If you post here the query part (i.e. after the `?`) of the actual URL you are putting in to the browser's address bar it would be useful -- I'd assume it would look something like `pageID=1&someRandomValue=582846b38bd99862bfe29199d0f60ba1` if so, that should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### the reason

In your sample URL you have hashes, these need to be url encoded using php's `urlencode` function. The reason for this is the `#` symbol is used to represent what's known as the `fragment` section of the URL. Anything after a hash is used at the browser side and is never sent to the server.

For more information on what the fragment is, see here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

And for more information about urlencode:

http://uk.php.net/urlencode

#### the solution

Your sample query string:

```
?pageNo=a&someRandomValue=aslkfdjslfhdskljOU#OsssssssIU#IO$U#IO$
```

Once URL encoded the URL should appear:

```
?pageNo=a&someRandomValue=aslkfdjslfhdskljOU%23OsssssssIU%23IO%24U%23IO%24
```

Note: you should URL encode each part of the name-value-pair separately, so:

```
$qry = '?' . urlencode('pageNo') . '=' . urlencode('a') . 
  '&' . urlencode('someRandomValue') . 
  '=' . urlencode('aslkfdjslfhdskljOU#OsssssssIU#IO$U#IO$');
```

Obviously as you know that most of the parts of the URL are hardcoded (and don't contain any illegal characters) you can get away with just doing the following:

```
$qry = '?pageNo=' . urlencode('a') . 
  '&someRandomValue=' . urlencode('aslkfdjslfhdskljOU#OsssssssIU#IO$U#IO$');
```

Or as would more likely be more useful in php:

```
$qry = '?pageNo=' . urlencode($pageNo) . 
  '&someRandomValue=' . urlencode($someRandomValue);
```

#### another way

If you have PHP 5 or above the following function could be of use, it takes a normal PHP array and converts it to a correctly encoded query string:

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

```
$data = array(
  'pageNo' => $pageNo,
  'someRandomValue' => $someRandomValue,
);

$qry = http_build_query( $data );
```

There is nothing better however, than knowing what is going on yourself. So, before using the above it might be best to read up on how URLs are formed, and possibly write your own version of `http_build_query` as a learning test.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/a/url_encoding.htm